# How to make a smooth transition from white to green?

Tags: android

There is the following function:

```
private void markTextView(int progress) {
    if (progress==5) {
        display.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    else {
        if (progress>5) {
            display.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 255));
        }
        else {
            display.setTextColor(Color.argb(0, 255, 0, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

This function changes the color of the text in Textview depending on the progress value. Progress value is an integer value from 0 to 10. If progress equals 10 it must have got a white color. If progress more than 5 then it must change a white color to green one smoothly. If progress less than 5 then it must change a white color to red one smoothly. Now, this function changes color without smooth transition as you can see. Please, tell me, how can I do a smooth transition? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

do you want an animation? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html#onAnimationEnd%28android.view.animation.Animation%29

or you could change the transparency over the course of a second etc with AlphaAnimation?

Or have some varying transition colours from white to green.